# C++ Builder XE2 - Checkbox hint doesnt show

Tags: c++, checkbox, tooltip, c++builder-xe2

As title suggests, even when I set Hint property of checkbox, tooltip is not displayed when mouse cursor is hovering over the control. There is no problem with the same Hint property over TButton control. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the `TCheckBox.ShowHint` or `TCheckBox.ParentShowHint` property set to True.

In the latter case, make sure the `Parent`'s `ShowHint/ParentShowHint` property is True, and so on up the Parent hierarchy.  If you reach the TForm an everything is enabled, then make sure `TApplication.ShowHint` property is true, and that there are no `OnHint` event handlers that could be discarding hint notifications from being dispatched to the `TCheckBox`.